# how can I prevent facebook from cropping external link thumbnails?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, thumbnails, facebook-timeline

Consider the image shown here http://www.facebook.com/CT.dineto under the "Please peruse our New Testing Menu" shared link.

The link points to this page:
http://www.dine.to/article2.html 
the og meta tags in there seem  OK according to the Facebook debug tool.

Notice the original  image is not square but 440x240px in size, but when shown on timeline as a thumbnail it gets cropped to a square and not just resized.

So my question: is there a way to have the thumbnails be resized versions of the original image rather than cropped and squared?